# How to Communication with the embedding page Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to implement messaging in the expansion. From content_script`a in background.js looked for a way to exchange documents using window.postMessage () and window.addEventListener (), but the messages are not sent. Through content_script I loaded js code in head.
Here's the code to background.js:

```
window.addEventListener ("message", function (event) {
  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  if (event.source! = window)
    return;

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
    console.log ("Content script received:" + event.data.text);
    port.postMessage (event.data.text);
  }
}, False);
```

This in content_script.js:

```
var s = document.createElement ('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL ('inject.js');
(Document.head || document.documentElement) .appendChild (s);
s.onload = function () {
    s.parentNode.removeChild (s);
};
```

This in inject.js:

```
window.postMessage ({type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!"}, "*");
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `window` object in the background page refers to itself, not the page currently viewed. As for what you are doing wrong - everything. Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and examined [the official sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener
```

and

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage
```

to pass messages between different js components. this answer helped me a lot: [Chrome Extension how to send data from content script to popup.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019958/chrome-extension-how-to-send-data-from-content-script-to-popup-html)

Comment: I can`t use chrome API in inject.js. What do?

Comment: you can if you inject the script using:

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "my_file.js"});

I used that script to send a message to the background.js using chrome.api.

Answer (score 0):

The basic flow of communication between a webpage and a content script or background script is:

Use content scripts to share DOM with the Web, use window.postMessage to send messages, and content.js uses extended API to forward the message to background.js after receiving the message.

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "name": "you name",
  "description": "you description",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**web.html**

```html
<body>
  <button id="me">Button</button>
</body>
```

**content.js**

```js
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(`${event.data} forwarded to the background.js`);
});

document.querySelector('#me').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.postMessage('Message from DOM', '*');
});
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => console.log(msg));
```

#### Long-lived connections

**content.js**

```js
const port = chrome.runtime.connect();
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
  port.postMessage(event.data);
});

document.querySelector('#me').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.postMessage('Message from DOM', '*');
});
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
  port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
    console.log('msg: ', msg);
  });
});
```

#### Another way to communicate directly with background.js

**manifest.json (add externally_connectable)**

```json
{
  "name": "you name",
  "description": "you description",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["http://localhost/*"]
  }
}
```

**web.html**

```html
<body>
  <button id="me">Button</button>
  <script>
   // Your extension ID, (pabahpeigkdpglhnjponplchdffchkdj).
    document.querySelector('#me').addEventListener('click', () => {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage('pabahpeigkdpglhnjponplchdffchkdj', 'Web Message');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(request => {
  console.log('request: ', request);
});
```