# In Chrome Extension, how to call a silent web page?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am screen scraping in my chrome extension.

I hit a button, and it should POST the data to a different website silently somehow. I have everything working except the POST part....

Something like CURL, but I am a newbie, so I have no clue of what lingo I should use in even describing this ;-)

[image]

Thanks for any leads stackoverflow!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019958/chrome-extension-how-to-send-data-from-content-script-to-popup-html

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   //thanks for getting me close