# Why and how do I resolve chrome.runtime.onMessage being undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

## Yes, I've searched and tried other answers.

I've been searching all over the place and found nothing for my problem, `chrome.runtime.onMessage` is undefined, a [Mozilla bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1435597) says that `chrome.runtime.lastError` existing prevents `chrome.runtime.onMessage` from existing, yet it doesn't.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692052/10974240) says to disable and reenable every extension? If *this* is the case, then that's going to be quite an inconvenient solution, as every time I'd run my code I would have to reload every extension I have.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179138/sending-message-from-popup-to-content-script-chrome-extension), I'm not sure about. It seems they do not have an issue with `chrome.runtime.onMessage`, but they had an issue with getting the active tab.

Theres way more questions, but these are the ones which links/keywords I remember.

What I'm trying to do: Connect my **`popup.js`** file to my **`content.js`** file to the webpage.

## Code

**`Manifest.json`**

```
{
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "First Extension",
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "tabCapture",
      "downloads",
      "storage",
      "declarativeContent",
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "icons": { 
         ...
      },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": { 
         ...
      }
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**`content.js`**

```js
//...

    chrome.runtime.lastError = undefined;
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) { //chrome.runtime.onMessage is undefined.
        console.log('something happened');
        myFunction(message.string);
    })

    window.onload = function() {
    myFunction(1);
    };

//...
```

**`popup.js`** (linked from **`popup.html`**

```js
var button = document.createElement('a');
button.className = 'genericButton round noSelect';
button.value = 'hello';
button.innerText = `Send to the page`;
document.getElementById('buttongroup').appendChild(abtn);
button.onclick = function(e) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        if (tabs[0]) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {string: abtn.value});
        };
    });
}
```

### If it helps:

```
Google Chrome   84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision    a6b12dfad6663f13a7e16e9a42a6a4975374096b-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#943}
JavaScript  V8 8.4.371.22
```

Comment: chrome.runtime.onMessage can't be undefined when used in a content script or any extension script. The only explanations for this error are that a) you run content.js as a page script e.g. via a DOM script element or b) you've reloaded the extension but didn't reload the web page tabs, c) it's a bug in the browser.

Comment: Responses:

a) I modify code with my content-script on the tab's document via document, and I'm not using this file to inject code with `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'content.js'})`.


b) I've reloaded this extension PLENTY of times; but, I have 30~ Chrome tabs open, do I need to quit Chrome and reopen it every time I need to test this extension? And if I put this on the Chrome Web Store, will any users have the same issue?

Comment: You probably try to add onMessage listener in response to some user action in the web page so after reloading/updating the extension your old "orphaned" content script is no longer connected to the extension. See the [source code of Stylus extension](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/tree/master/content/apply.js) for an example of handling this problem.