# Get document.body of webpage from popup while using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools

I have a basic Chrome extension which needs to access `document.body` of the webpage through popup.

Currently, when I try to open popup & console log `document.body`, it logs the popup's `document.body` while I want the website's `document.body`.

How do I do that?

## manifest.json

```
{
  "description": "Demo ext",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Demo ext",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon-48.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon-32.png",
    "theme_icons": [
      {
        "light": "icons/icon-32-light.png",
        "dark": "icons/icon-32.png",
        "size": 32
      }
    ],
    "default_title": "Demo ext",
    "default_popup": "popup/index.html"
  }
}
```

## popup/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo ext</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title should be the websites which we are on </h1>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## popup/app.js

```
function main() {
  console.log(document.body)
  var title = document.createElement('div')
  title.innerHTML = document.title
  document.body.appendChild(title)
}

main()
```

I want the `document.body` logged here to be of the website. How should I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236/how-to-access-the-webpage-dom-rather-than-the-extension-page-dom)

Comment: yep it looks like a possible duplicate but the executeScript method felt hackish. so i went with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023723/6141587) & it helped me solve it :)

Comment: There's nothing hackish in executeScript.

Comment: by hackish i meant weird syntax. i had to convert that javascript into strings. i think it can also be provided a js filepath but the other way is much nicer so i used that.

Comment: Depending on the actual/final goal that other approach may be way too over-engineered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed Content scripts were the way to go. I tried it but it didn't work for me but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023723/6141587) solved it all.

Just linking it since it explains everything better than I can :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you review this [Chrome Extension Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

> If your extension needs to interact with web pages, then it needs a content script. A content script is some JavaScript that executes in the context of a page that's been loaded into the browser. Think of a content script as part of that loaded page, not as part of the extension it was packaged with (its parent extension).

Content scripts can access Chrome APIs used by their parent extension by exchanging messages with the extension. They can also access the URL of an extension's file with chrome.runtime.getURL() and use the result the same as other URLs.

Comment: thank you. I found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023723/6141587) :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `popup.js` you can execute a script to interact with content using the `chrome.scripting.executeScript` like this:

`popup.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="changeColor"></button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js`

```
// When the button is clicked, inject setPageBackgroundColor into current page
changeColor.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: setPageBackgroundColor,
  });
});

// The body of this function will be executed as a content script inside the
// current page
function setPageBackgroundColor() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("color", ({ color }) => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
}
```