# How do i make my chrome extension appear as a pop-up

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I want to make my chrome extension appear out like a pop-up . Is that possible ? 
As I cant handle the data from background script to popup.html as the chrome extension would not be rendered yet.
background script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "hello"){
            createTable(request.message);
        }
        return true;
    });
```

request.message can be accessed but cant be added to the chrome extension

Comment: First you need to clarify what exactly is that "pop-up" and how it should look. Also there may be an entirely different solution depending on what that "data" is and how you want to handle it.

Comment: This is the situation. I am taking some data from the website and sending it to the extension's javascript (background.js) but the extension DOM                                   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "hello"){
            createTable(request.message);
        }
        return true;
    }); , the request. message has the data i want but i cant add it to the chrome extension as it not rendered yet.

Comment: So i thought of taking my chrome out as a pop-up box .

Comment: @siri I think this is exactly what you need https://stackoverflow.com/q/20019958/6141587