# Send message from page to popup after click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Let me start with the fact that I did not find such information, so I am asking.
I would like to make an extension that will get the clicked item and send it to the popup.
I mean something like:

```
document.addEventListener ('click', (e) => {
             console.log (e.target);
             e.target;
         })
```

So far I am not able to do it, I was based on this:
[Chrome Extension how to send data from content script to popup.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019958/chrome-extension-how-to-send-data-from-content-script-to-popup-html)
but I can't send the click information.
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: The popup is a separate window so you can't send DOM events.

Comment: now I get it. Thank you