# How can I pass data using chrome.runtime from content.js to popup.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, runtime

I have this code in `content.js`, wherein I want to pass the `listData` to `popup.js` using `chrome.runtime`. how can I possibly do that?

```
var dataImage: any = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
var dataName: any = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
var dataJobTitle: any = document.getElementsByClassName("title");

var listData: Array<any> = [];

for (let x in [dataImage, dataName]) {
  const image = dataImage[x]?.firstElementChild?.src;
  const name = dataName[x]?.innerText;
  const job = dataJobTitle[x]?.firstElementChild?.innerText;

  listData.push({ image: image, name: name, job: job });
}
console.log(listData);
```

These `listData` will be map as html `<li>` in popup

Answer (score 0):

```
**in contentScript.js:**
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
     total_elements: totalElements // or whatever you want to send
 });

 **in eventPage.js (your background page):**
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse){
   localStorage["total_elements"] = request.total_elements;
});
```

reference : [Chrome Extension how to send data from content script to popup.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019958/chrome-extension-how-to-send-data-from-content-script-to-popup-html)

Comment: is there a way to directly do the addListener in popup.js? i tried to put the addListener in popup, but I receiving undefined per element in total_elements