# How do you get the source of a website from a chromium extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to create an application that can read the values in the HTML and output them in the popup. I am confused, how can I get the HTML source of the website that the user is connected to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a content script to insert a JavaScript file into the page (see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/)).  You can use `document.documentElement.innerHTML` to access the complete innerHTML of a page. (See also [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023723/17115294))

Comment: That gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')"